# How do I query the frequency each date in my table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (postgresql) with rows for each date a person made a visit.
I'm trying to create a visualization of the total number of visits (by all people) each day during a three month period (1/1 - 3/31) this year compared to the same period last year.

The final goal is to create a time-series line graph to visualize the magnitude of differences by day between years.

I'm using ipython-sql and sqlmagic to query the data.  I'm hoping to send the results to a pandas dataframe and use it in a bokeh visualization or something.

I have no idea how to even approach this query.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest problems totally baffle me.

select 
    visit_date, count(*) as cnt
from 
    mytable
group by 
    visit_date
where
    visit_date between 'startdate' and 'enddate';

doh.